# Oracle Personal Edition 21c: Listener cannot find service name

Tags: oracle, database-connection

I'm getting started with Oracle Personal Edition.  Installation was successful. Trying to connect to the database and getting stuck.  I have:

```
tnsping xe2

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 16-APR-2022 17:14:25

Copyright (c) 1997, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\app\geral\product\21c\homes\OraDB21Home1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.docker.internal)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)))
OK (10 msec)
```

which seems promising.  In sqlplus I can:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Apr 16 17:14:40 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0
```

then show the pdbs:

```
SQL> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 XEPDB1                         READ WRITE NO
SQL>
```

So, I now want to try to connect to the CON_NAME XEPDB1 using that TNS entry I tested:

```
SQL> conn foo@xe2
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
```

At this point, I'm stuck.  How do I troubleshoot and resolve the cause of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Your listener is on and working but your instance has not dynamically registered it’s services with it nor are they statically part of your listener config.

Easiest option is to get your instance to register itself. Look at the instance parameter `local_listener`, this needs to point to your listener running on `(HOST = host.docker.internal)(PORT = 1521)`, you can do this with a tnsname that points to the same listener or you can take advantage of EZConnect syntax and just use the host name (the default port is 1521 anyway). I would recommend setting up a tnsnames entry just called `listener` which contains the host and port but no connect_data.

(Using EZconnect)

```
Alter system set local_listener='host.docker.internal';
```

This will self-validate .

You then just need to wait for automatic registration to occur, you can see this happening in your listener logs, you can trigger it manually with `alter system register;` and you can confirm it’s happened by looking at the results of `lsnrctl status host.docker.internal`.

Comment: I was just about to try this, then noticed that the listener now reports all the services. Happened sometime after a reboot, not sure when.

Comment: @Andrew Sayer - actually no need to set LOCAL_LISTENER at all.  By default, it will use the local host name and port 1521.  Though I've never used docker, so it might be a bit different in how it treats the host name.